# Null id generated Error with Embedded Primary keys

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

My Data Model involves below Entity
1.

```
    @Embeddable
    @Data
    public class BlockAttributeID implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "block_id")
    Long blockID;

    String attribute;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof BlockAttributeID)) return false;
        return blockID != null && attribute != null && blockID.equals(((BlockAttributeID) o).getBlockID()) && attribute.equals(((BlockAttributeID) o).getAttribute());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

}
```

2. 

```
 @Data
 @Table(name = "block_attribute")
 @Entity
 public class BlockAttribute {

  @EmbeddedId
  BlockAttributeID blockAttributeID;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinColumn(name = "block_id")
  Block block;

  String label;


  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  Type type;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  Unit unit;

  String value;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (!(o instanceof BlockAttribute)) return false;
      return blockAttributeID != null && blockAttributeID.equals(((BlockAttribute) o).getBlockAttributeID());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return getClass().hashCode();
  }

}
```

3. 

```
@Table(name = "block")
@Entity
@Data
public class Block {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "native")
    @Column(name = "block_id")
    Long blockID;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "site_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    Site site;

    String name;

    @Column(name = "external_reference")
    String externalReference;

    @Column(name = "block_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    BlockType blockType;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "valid_from")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    LocalDateTime validFrom;

    @Column(name = "valid_to")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    LocalDateTime validTo;

    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    BlockStatus status;

    @Column(name = "source_reference_system")
    Integer sourceReferenceSystem;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "block", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<BlockAttribute> blockAttributes = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "block", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<BlockBoundary> blockBoundaries = new HashSet<>();

    public void addBlockAttributes(BlockAttribute blockAttribute) {
        blockAttributes = this.getBlockAttributes();
        blockAttributes.add(blockAttribute);
        this.setBlockAttributes(blockAttributes);
    }

    public void addBlockBoundaries(BlockBoundary blockBoundary) {
        blockBoundaries = this.getBlockBoundaries();
        blockBoundaries.add(blockBoundary);
        this.setBlockBoundaries(blockBoundaries);
    }

}
```

Now I was going through https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

this tutorial and tried to replicate it with my code but the I keep on getting null id generated for:class BlockAttribute

using this logic to save

```
    block = blockRepository.save(block);
    blockAttribute.setBlock(block);
    blockBoundary.setBlock(block);
    blockAttributeRepository.save(blockAttribute);
    blockBoundaryRepository.save(blockBoundary);
```

My thinking is that unless blockRepository save is not called blockId is not generated and it causes ID null error, but i am saving it before then using it any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi, what are the database and the version used?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this by putting the mapping relation inside the embedded key

```
 public BlockAttributeID(Block block, String attribute) {
    this.block = block;
    this.attribute = attribute;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "block_id")
Block block;

String attribute;

public BlockAttributeID() {

}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof BlockAttributeID)) return false;
    return block != null && attribute != null && block.equals(((BlockAttributeID) o).getBlock()) && attribute.equals(((BlockAttributeID) o).getAttribute());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getClass().hashCode();
}
```

And then setting ID manually as it was not getting generated own its own.

```
    blockAttribute.setBlockAttributeID(new BlockAttributeID(block, completeBlockDTO.getBlockAttributeDTO().getAttribute()));
```

Referenced the same author tutorial for the same.
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Alternatively you could have added the @MapsId("blockID") annotation on your BlockAttribute.block OneToOne mapping to tell it to use the value from the relationship to set the blockID property within your embedded ID.